# Schema markup for Q&A page

Tags: html, schema.org

I am trying to implement schema.org tags in my website. I need to implement a Q&A page. however when I try to add all three tags in the same HTML page they are all messed up with each other. I am trying to do it the same as the Stack Overflow website. I need to know what I am doing wrong here is my code

```
<html lang="en" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage" <meta property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="You can ask EasySchools about any school you want to know its details such like fees, website, phone number, facebook, certificate, facilities, location. ">
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="https://www.easyschools.org/backend/website/social.png ">
```

It’s supposed to end here and then start Question and Answers item tags but they are all mixed up with each other. Here is my question and answers code:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question" class="col-md-9 text-left">
  <link itemprop="image" href="https://www.easyschools.org/uploads/main/images/Dn64LgiE9cJ5997qxyFc0rl7Omf9AzECsfL0HYBS.png">
  <h4 itemprop="name">تقديم المدارس الناشونيل شهر 5 او 6 فى مدينة نصر وا التجمع</h4>
</div>


<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer">
  <div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-12">
    <h4 class="user pull-left">EasySchools</h4>
    <h5 class="pull-right">2018-05-13 12:09:01</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 pic"><img src=https://www.easyschools.org/backend/website/pic/thumb.png alt="EasySchools-answer"></div>
  <div class="col-md-7 text-left padding-fix">
    <h4 itemprop="text">دي حضرتك المدارس الي موجوده ف التجمع تقدر تحدد المدرسه الي حضرتك عايزها وتدخل عل المدرسه هتلقي كل التفاصيل الي حضرتك عايزها زي لينك التقديم و ارقام التليفوناتhttps://www.easyschools.org/en/schools/advsearch?city=cairo&amp;district=new-cairo&amp;rangeOne=1&amp;rangeTwo=250000</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 text-right"></div>
</div>
```

here is the link of my page to test if needed:

https://www.easyschools.org/en/showQuestion/174

Comment: 1) Your start `html` tag misses the closing `>`. Is this a copy-paste error, or do you actually miss it? 2) What does "they are all messed up with each other" or "mixed up with each other" mean?

Comment: @unor yeah i missed it by mistake in here.
i mean messed up that accepted answer and suggested answers should below to the Question schema while when i test it says it belong to the QApage so i need to know how to differentiate it? you can test the link to understand what i mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use properties to link the items. Currently you have a `QAPage`, a `Question`, and an `Answer`, but they aren’t related in any way.

Check the relevant type pages on http://schema.org/:

- [**`Question`**](http://schema.org/Question) defines the properties [`acceptedAnswer`](http://schema.org/acceptedAnswer) and [`suggestedAnswer`](http://schema.org/suggestedAnswer) to link to an `Answer`,
  and [`mainEntityOfPage`](http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage) to link to the `QAPage`.
- [**`Answer`**](http://schema.org/Answer) provides the property [`parentItem`](http://schema.org/parentItem) to link to the `Question`,
  and [`mainEntityOfPage`](http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage) to link to the `QAPage`.
- [**`QAPage`**](http://schema.org/QAPage) provides the property [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity) to link to the `Question`.

Note that you typically don’t have to provide the properties in both directions. So, for example, if you use `acceptedAnswer`/`suggestedAnswer` in the `Question`, you typically don’t have to use `parentItem` in the `Answer`. However, in theory, some consumers might only support one direction.

If you can’t nest the HTML elements, you can use `itemref`.